# Snap: correct use of PreRun hook

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I cant figure out how to run a function before any template loads.
For instance:
I have a function called 'authenticate' that returns a Maybe value. I want to run it before any template is loaded and then redirect conditionally.
I believe the PreRun and OnLoad hooks should do this but I don't know how to use them.

Can someone please show the correct usage of those hooks to implement the above example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PreRun hooks are gone in Heist 0.10.  If the stuff you're trying to call involves template processing, then you can do it as a compiled splice or a load time splice.  If it involves web server processing, then do it in the Handler or Snap monad before your template is rendered.

Comment: Thanks, mightybyte. I suppose, I had to much of Rails where there is a "before_filter" which allows you to run a function before any handler is executed ... Anyway, what I want is, for instance, to run a function "authorize" before any handler is executed. So this function would check the "user" session key and if such key exists then the handler executes, requested page is loaded. If such key does not exist then the user gets forwarded to login page and login process initiated. I could create such a function and stick it in every handler but I thought I could do it in a preLoad hook or so ...

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like something that should be done on the route level.  Something like `authorize >> route myRoutes`.